# string methods - replace(oldChar,newChar)

Tags: java

I've got to find a solution to find the next largest number, based on a sequence of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 input by the user.

For example is the user inputs

> 5647382901

then my function has to change it to

> 5647382910

My below code replace my last 2 x digits with the temporary char K, but I need it to replace just the last digit. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
public class NextLargest {
  int a = 100;
  public static void nextLargest(String a){
    long newNumber = Long.valueOf(a);
    int last = (int)(newNumber%10);
    int lastByOne = (int)(newNumber/10)%10;
    if(last > lastByOne){
        char k = a.charAt(a.length()-2); // 0
        a = a.replace(a.charAt(a.length()-2),a.charAt(a.length() -1) ); // 5647382911
        System.out.println(b); // 5647382911
        a = a.replace(a.charAt(a.length()-1),k);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    System.out.println(a);

    System.out.println(last);
    System.out.println(lastByOne);
  }
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number");
    String number = scan.next();
    nextLargest(number);
}
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the replace method: `Returns a string resulting from replacing *all occurrences* of oldChar in this string with newChar.` In short: You cannot use the method replace(char, char) if you only want to replace a specific place in a string.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with replace method is that it changes all the occurences of your old char with your new char and thats why you can't switch the last 2 digits you can try it using this solution :

```
    long newNumber = Long.valueOf(a);
    int last = (int)(newNumber%10);
    int lastByOne = (int)(newNumber/10)%10;
    if(last > lastByOne){
        newNumber= newNumber - lastByOne*9  + last*9 ;

        }
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! my final number :"+newNumber);
    a = String.valueOf(newNumber);
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! my final number :"+a);
```

}